# Tensorflow.js importing a frozen model results in missing a dict value ImageTensor error

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have exported a pre-trained deeplab v3 model using the tensorflowjs-converter. I found out the output_node_name and used the following command to quantize and export the model

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_frozen_model --output_node_names='SemanticPredictions' --quantization_bytes 1 --saved_model_tags=serve frozen_inference_graph.pb deeplab_web_model_quant
```

The model is exported and I have the following directory structure

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4194304 Jan 28 20:41 group1-shard1of10
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4194304 Jan 28 20:41 group1-shard2of10
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4194304 Jan 28 20:41 group1-shard3of10
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4194304 Jan 28 20:41 group1-shard4of10
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4194304 Jan 28 20:41 group1-shard5of10
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4194304 Jan 28 20:41 group1-shard6of10
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4194304 Jan 28 20:41 group1-shard7of10
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4194304 Jan 28 20:41 group1-shard8of10
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4194304 Jan 28 20:41 group1-shard9of10
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3257567 Jan 28 20:41 group1-shard10of10
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   94668 Jan 28 20:41 weights_manifest.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  263831 Jan 28 20:41 tensorflowjs_model.pb
```

So I zip this directory transfer locally and use the following to load the exported model

```
const model = await tf.loadFrozenModel(
    'http://localhost:8080/tensorflowjs_model.pb',
    'http://localhost:8080/weights_manifest.json');
```

I get a weird error like this:

```
graph_executor.ts:382 Uncaught (in promise) Error: The dict provided in model.execute(dict) has the keys [], but is missing the required keys: [ImageTensor].
    at e.checkInput (graph_executor.ts:382)
    at e.execute (graph_executor.ts:148)
    at e.execute_ (frozen_model.ts:204)
    at e.predict (frozen_model.ts:155)
    at HTMLButtonElement.runButton.onclick (index.js:13)
```

I dig a bit deeper into what this ImageTensor is all about. It is listed as a input tensor name in the model. However, while exporting only output_node_names can be specified. Is there anyway to debug this ? I have no idea how to proceed as the error message doesn't reveal much.

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The predict method in the FrozenModel has following signature:

```
predict(
  inputs: tfc.Tensor|tfc.Tensor[]|tfc.NamedTensorMap,
  config?: tfc.ModelPredictConfig): tfc.Tensor
  |tfc.Tensor[]|tfc.NamedTensorMap
```

you need to provide the input tensor as the first parameter when calling the predict method, this value should be corresponding to the ImageTensor definition of your python model.

Comment: I have not made it to the predict call yet. I get the error while loading the model